# docker-compose.yml override remove build for image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

and `docker-compose.override.yml`:

```
services:
  app:
    image: my_repo/my_app:my_tag
```

When I do `docker-compose up`, it actually does `build: .` instead of using the overriden `image: my_repo/my_app:my_tag`.

I guess I should go for some kind of `build: false` or `build: none` to make sure it reads the `image` attribute, shouldn't I? Since override seems to act like a merge, it would result as if both entries were there:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: my_repo/my_app:my_tag
```

and it seems like `build` is prioritary to `image` (from [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)).

Comment: You can [`docker-compose up --no-build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) to skip the build. I don't understand the requirement for an `override` file - if you specify `image` and `build` then `docker-compose up` will build the artifact and tag the built image as whatever is specified as the `image` otherwise use `docker-compose up --no-build` to skip the build and use the `image` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was able to remove the `build` portion from the rendered config with `!reset null`.

take these two files as an example:

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/docker/Dockerfile
```

*docker-compose.dev.yml*

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    image: my/dev/image:0.9
    build: !reset null
```

when viewing the rendered config with `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml config`, this is the result:

```yaml
name: test
services:
  backend:
    image: my/dev/image:0.9
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: test_default
```

this also works when using `docker-compose.override.yml` (i.e. when not specifying multiple compose files manually)

this is also mentioned in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/13-merge/

tested with compose version 2.18.1.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct way to do it is to have a base `docker-compose.yml` like :

```
services:
  app:
    image: my_repo/my_app:my_tag
```

and the `docker-compose.override.yml` :

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

This way when you launch `docker-compose up` the image will be built with build context `.`

Another example with `docker-compose.override.yml` with different image :

```
services:
  app:
    image : my_repo/other_image:tag
```

And here the image from `docker-compose.override.yml` will take precedence.

Comment: So `image` cannot override `build`? Kind of sad limitation

Comment: Opened an issue for this: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7231